# VB.Net check punctuation

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, keypress

i have a keypress event that limits the input to be only numbers like so:

```
Private Sub txtWeight_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtWeight.KeyPress

    If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

but i want to add the possibility to type periods too, so i tried to change the code to:

```
Private Sub txtWeight_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtWeight.KeyPress

    If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

But as you know the program lets me type every punctuation and i want to limit it to only "." how do i check what punctuation is being typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
e.Handled = e.KeyChar <> "."c AndAlso Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)
```

Comment: Thank you, didnt think it was that easy, i changed it to: "If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not e.KeyChar = "." AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then" and works perfectly

Comment: @NomeCognome, it is bad form to use `Not` and `=` when there's a `<>` operator but, if you were going to do that then that's still bad form because you ought to refactor that to `If Not (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) OrElse e.KeyChar = "." OrElse Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) Then`.